# How can we find the Tumbleweeds?

Tags: discussion, badges, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016, tumbleweed-badge

[One of the Winter Bash 2016 hats](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/lifesaver) involves answering a question which qualifies for the Tumbleweed badge.

There doesn't seem to be a great way to search for questions which qualify for this tag (no search parameter for comments?), and some of the parameters are a bit vague. How can we best go about find such questions to answer?

Ideally there should be a way to search through the available questions, or at least filter by tag.

Comment: Carefully, very carefully.

Comment: Shameless plug http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148570/badger-the-tumbleweed-detector

Comment: @BhargavRao you're not going to advertise it with your custom link so you can get Amped Up? :P

Comment: Haha, @StephenLeppik, No need, I've already got it on SO. :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as Winter Bash 2016 has long ended, questions about it are now irrelevant.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can find them [here](/help/badges/38/tumbleweed). (The list of questions that earned Tumbleweed.) You can also use the [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/508754/tumbleweed-prevention) mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: True, but searching and filtering would make finding good ones much easier.

Answer (score 9):

You can search questions that are about to get the Tumbleweed badge (but have not yet gotten it) with the Data Explorer. I found a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/508754/tumbleweed-prevention) that lists them all, I modified it a bit so you can search for a certain tag as well (put in something like `javascript`): 
[Tumbleweed Prevention with Tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/605381/tumbleweed-prevention-with-tag)

Comment: Dammit I was writing in the middle of writing that query.

Comment: * With the caveat that this list may be up to a week out of date.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did: visit the **Help Center** > **Badges**, filter > **bronze** > **Tumbleweed**

In an instant you see every user who was awarded the Tumbleweed badge, when the questions were posted and the number of rep the OP has. This last data is vital because unless the OP accepts an answer, no hat will be awarded. A user with 1 rep will not likely return to the site and accept an answer—however good it may be.

For example on Movies&TV the badge has been [awarded 289 times](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/badges/40/tumbleweed)

Comment: Sure, +1 for progress on my Sportsmanship badge. And also for giving my answer the attention it needs for Good Answer.